# Python pyad issue: AttributeError: module 'pyad.pyad' has no attribute 'adquery'

Tags: python, python-3.x, active-directory, python-module, pyad

I am experiencing an issue when trying to use Python's pyad module.

```
from pyad import *
pyad.set_defaults(ldap_server=adserver, username="", password="")
q = pyad.adquery.ADQuery()
-------------------------
AttributeError: module 'pyad.pyad' has no attribute 'adquery'
```

Windows 10; Python 3.8.3; and I did a force install of pyad and pywin32

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `import pyad.adquery` instead of `from pyad import *`, like [their examples show](https://zakird.github.io/pyad/pyad.html#searching-active-directory).

It may not be the issue. The pyad library [does define `__all__`](https://github.com/zakird/pyad/blob/master/pyad/__init__.py) in their code, but there seems to be [a lot of caveats to how `import *` works](https://medium.com/@s16h/importing-star-in-python-88fe9e8bd4d2), so it's worth a try.

Comment: Thanks @Gabriel! It looks like I was able to take your advice and get it working.  

To get it working I had to:  

`import pyad  
from pyad import adquery`  

Otherwise I would get:  

`pyad.pyad_setdefaults(ldap_server=adserver, username="", password="")  
NameError: name 'pyad' is not defined`  

If there's a cleaner way to do the imports, please let me know. I'm pretty new to Python.